# Flutter : I/flutter ( 8345): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to access data from my firebase to display in my app. And I have been working on this app with Firebase for a few days, but today I got an error saying
my code :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream:
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Something went wrong!');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      return ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        children:
                            snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                          Map<String, dynamic> data =
                              document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: HomeDisplayScreen(
                              videoLink: data['videoLink'],
                              imageUrl: data['imageUrl'],
                              title: data['title'],
                              likes: data['likes'],
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
                    })
```

the error:

```
W/Firestore( 8345): (24.1.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(videos order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore( 8345): (24.1.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/*****@gmail.com order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/flutter ( 8345): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

I also changed my security rules to this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write : if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Still, I am getting the same error

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear. The rules you're using do not allow the function call to be executed. So... for us to help, we would need to see the code you're using to make that call. Please update the question with your code and take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already fix your problem but the error you got, was because of your Firestore rules so to fix it go into firestore rules and change them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `projectFolder/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` try add the following and rebuild your app:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: nothing changed, it gets the same thing which I showed in the question.